# DataPager jump back to first pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datapager

I have a strange problem that I don't understand about DataPager. After changing the page set (pages 6 - 10 for example), and clicking on a page (6, 7, 8, 9 or 10), it will displa to the first set of pages counting from 1 again.

Let me explain. I have a ASP.Net page with Listview and DataPager.

```
<asp:ListView ... DataSourceId="EntityDataSource" DataKeyNames="id">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:DataPager runat="server"  ID="DataPager1" PageSize="15">
            <Fields>
                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField FirstPageText="&lt;&lt;" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False"
                        ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                <asp:NumericPageField />
                 <asp:NextPreviousPagerField LastPageText="&gt;&gt;" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False"
                        ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DataPager>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

To update the data, I do a DataBind during PreRender.

```
 protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
 {
      lstview1.DataBind();
      base.OnPreRender(e);
 }
```

All this works, but the problem is that the set of pages will not remember during postbacks. Let me explain this.

By first request of page, the pages show:

<< 1 2 3 4 5 ... >>

By clicking the ..., the next set of pages will be displayed (and also the data of page 6 will be displayed)

<< ... 6 7 8 9 10 ... >>

But when I click on page 7 to 10, the pages text will display the first set of pages 1-5.

Can someone explain why this happen? Miss I something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are databinding in the wrong place. I think this resets the paging. Are you sure it doesn't work if you remove the `lstview1.DataBind();`?

You can check this page for an example:
http://www.beansoftware.com/asp.net-tutorials/listview-datapager.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Removing the DataBindg doesn't work. I'll read the page.